# Overriding classes in an EF Core data access layer

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My company has a core database schema that's shared between all of our customers, and we then have customer-specific schemas for each customer. The core DB itself never changes. We're looking to make a NuGet package for the core data access project, then have our customer-specific projects just extend from that one.

I have everything set up to inherit from the core project and that works correctly. My problem now is that we need to add a navigation property to one of the core classes. The table is exactly the same, but we've added a customer-specific table with a FK to this core table and thus need a navigation property. Is it possible to do this, essentially override the core class with the customer-specific one?

As an example, here's a core class:

```
public class Shape
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A customer now wants to add colors that each shape can have:

```
public class ShapeColor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string HexCode { get; set; }
    public int ShapeId { get; set; }

    public Shape Shape { get; set; }
}
```

The core class hasn't changed in the DB, but we need a navigation property to be able to configure it for EF Core:

```
public class Shape
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ShapeColor> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: They need to define the relationship in the `OnModelCreating` method of `DbContext` Class.

Comment: Customer can declare derived model `ColoredShape : Shape` with `Colors` property. But you need to add inheritance capability to `Shape`s table.

Comment: is this question need to be solved with database table inheritance?

Comment: As soon as you don't need collection navigation property, no configuration is needed (since `Shape` and `ShapeId` properties in `ShapeColor` class define the desired relationship by convention).

Answer (score 3):

`AppDbContext` class should be inheritable and the method `OnModelCreating` is anyhow overridable. In the `OnModelCreating` method of derived `DbContext` class, add the following code to define the relationship.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // modelBuilder.Entity<Shape>().HasKey(x=>x.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ShapeColor>(x =>
    {
        // x.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        x.Property(p => p.ShapeId).IsRequired();
        x.HasOne<Shape>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(y => y.ShapeId);
    });
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Also, I have decorated `Id` property in each class using `[Key]` attribute. If you don't want to decorate with `[Key]` attribute, use Fluent expression and define Id properties.

Comment: Just a sidenote: Decorating a Id with the [Key] attribute is not necessary; by convention, a property named Id or <type name>Id will be configured as the key of an entity. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys#conventions)